# flash light is not turned on

Tags: android, flashlight

This is my source code for barcode snanner which I post again.  I edited my code. The problem is, when i run app, flash light is not turned on automatically. I added permission in manifest file, but flash light did not turn on. please help me where is the problem? I am using HTC wIldfire s mobile.

```
public final class CameraManager {

 private static final String TAG = CameraManager.class.getSimpleName();

 private static final int MIN_FRAME_WIDTH = 240;
 private static final int MIN_FRAME_HEIGHT = 240;
 private static final int MAX_FRAME_WIDTH = 480;
 private static final int MAX_FRAME_HEIGHT = 360;

 private static CameraManager cameraManager;

 static final int SDK_INT; // Later we can use Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
 static {
  int sdkInt;
  try {
 sdkInt = Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK);
 } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
 // Just to be safe
 sdkInt = 10000;
 }
 SDK_INT = sdkInt;
  }

 private final Context context;
 private Camera camera;
  private Rect framingRect;
 private Rect framingRectInPreview;
 private boolean initialized;
 private boolean previewing;
  /**
 * Preview frames are delivered here, which we pass on to the registered handler.  
   Make  
 sure to
  * clear the handler so it will only receive one message.
 */
   private final PreviewCallback previewCallback;
  /** Autofocus callbacks arrive here, and are dispatched to the Handler which  
   requested them. */
   private final AutoFocusCallback autoFocusCallback;

   /**
   * Initializes this static object with the Context of the calling Activity.
  *
  * @param context The Activity which wants to use the camera.
  */
   public static void init(Context context) {
  if (cameraManager == null) {
   cameraManager = new CameraManager(context);
   }
  }

      /**
  * Gets the CameraManager singleton instance.
   *
   * @return A reference to the CameraManager singleton.
  */
 public static CameraManager get() {
  return cameraManager;
  }

 private CameraManager(Context context) {

 this.context = context;
 this.configManager = new CameraConfigurationManager(context);

 // Camera.setOneShotPreviewCallback() has a race condition in Cupcake, so we use the  
  older
  // Camera.setPreviewCallback() on 1.5 and earlier. For Donut and later, we need to   
   \     use
  // the more efficient one shot callback, as the older one can swamp the system and  
  cause it
 // to run out of memory. We can't use SDK_INT because it was introduced in the 
  Donut  
  SDK.
 //useOneShotPreviewCallback = Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) >  
 Build.VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE;
  useOneShotPreviewCallback = Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) > 3; // 3 = Cupcake

 previewCallback = new PreviewCallback(configManager, useOneShotPreviewCallback);
 autoFocusCallback = new AutoFocusCallback();
}

/**
* Opens the camera driver and initializes the hardware parameters.
*
* @param holder The surface object which the camera will draw preview frames into.
* @throws IOException Indicates the camera driver failed to open.
 */
 public void openDriver(SurfaceHolder holder) throws IOException {
 if (camera == null) {
camera = Camera.open();
 if (camera == null) {
 throw new IOException();
 }
 camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);

  if (!initialized) {
  initialized = true;
  configManager.initFromCameraParameters(camera);
  }
 configManager.setDesiredCameraParameters(camera);

  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
 //ÊÇ·ñÊ¹ÓÃÇ°µÆ

 //      if (prefs.getBoolean(PreferencesActivity.KEY_FRONT_LIGHT, false)) {
   //        FlashlightManager.enableFlashlight();
  //      }
  FlashlightManager.enableFlashlight();
   }
 }

 /**
 * Closes the camera driver if still in use.
  */
  public void closeDriver() {
  if (camera != null) {
 FlashlightManager.disableFlashlight();
 camera.release();
 camera = null;
 }
 }

  /**
   * Asks the camera hardware to begin drawing preview frames to the screen.
  */
 public void startPreview() {
  if (camera != null && !previewing) {
 camera.startPreview();
 previewing = true;
  }
  }

 /**
  * Tells the camera to stop drawing preview frames.
  */
   public void stopPreview() {
  if (camera != null && previewing) {
 if (!useOneShotPreviewCallback) {
 camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
 }
 camera.stopPreview();
 previewCallback.setHandler(null, 0);
autoFocusCallback.setHandler(null, 0);
previewing = false;
 }
  }

 /**
 * A single preview frame will be returned to the handler supplied. The data will  
 arrive as byte[]
 * in the message.obj field, with width and height encoded as message.arg1 and  
 message.arg2,
 * respectively.
 *
 * @param handler The handler to send the message to.
 * @param message The what field of the message to be sent.
*/
 public void requestPreviewFrame(Handler handler, int message) {
if (camera != null && previewing) {
previewCallback.setHandler(handler, message);
 if (useOneShotPreviewCallback) {
camera.setOneShotPreviewCallback(previewCallback);
 } else {
  camera.setPreviewCallback(previewCallback);
 }
 }
 }

/**
* Asks the camera hardware to perform an autofocus.
*
 * @param handler The Handler to notify when the autofocus completes.
 * @param message The message to deliver.
*/
  public void requestAutoFocus(Handler handler, int message) {
  if (camera != null && previewing) {
 autoFocusCallback.setHandler(handler, message);
  //Log.d(TAG, "Requesting auto-focus callback");
 camera.autoFocus(autoFocusCallback);
 }
}

/**
* Calculates the framing rect which the UI should draw to show the user where to  
  place  the
* barcode. This target helps with alignment as well as forces the user to hold the  
 device
* far enough away to ensure the image will be in focus.
 *
* @return The rectangle to draw on screen in window coordinates.
*/
 public Rect getFramingRect() {
Point screenResolution = configManager.getScreenResolution();
 if (framingRect == null) {
 if (camera == null) {
  return null;
 }
int width = screenResolution.x * 3 / 4;
 if (width < MIN_FRAME_WIDTH) {
width = MIN_FRAME_WIDTH;
} else if (width > MAX_FRAME_WIDTH) {
 width = MAX_FRAME_WIDTH;
}
  int height = screenResolution.y * 3 / 4;
 if (height < MIN_FRAME_HEIGHT) {
 height = MIN_FRAME_HEIGHT;
} else if (height > MAX_FRAME_HEIGHT) {
 height = MAX_FRAME_HEIGHT;
 }
 int leftOffset = (screenResolution.x - width) / 2;
int topOffset = (screenResolution.y - height) / 2;
 framingRect = new Rect(leftOffset, topOffset, leftOffset + width, topOffset +  
 height);
 Log.d(TAG, "Calculated framing rect: " + framingRect);
 }
  return framingRect;
}

  /**
  * Like {@link #getFramingRect} but coordinates are in terms of the preview frame,
 * not UI / screen.
 */
 public Rect getFramingRectInPreview() {
if (framingRectInPreview == null) {
 Rect rect = new Rect(getFramingRect());
Point cameraResolution = configManager.getCameraResolution();
Point screenResolution = configManager.getScreenResolution();
 rect.left = rect.left * cameraResolution.x / screenResolution.x;
 rect.right = rect.right * cameraResolution.x / screenResolution.x;
rect.top = rect.top * cameraResolution.y / screenResolution.y;
rect.bottom = rect.bottom * cameraResolution.y / screenResolution.y;
framingRectInPreview = rect;
}
  return framingRectInPreview;
  }










final class FlashlightManager {

 private static final String TAG = FlashlightManager.class.getSimpleName();

  private static final Object iHardwareService;
 private static final Method setFlashEnabledMethod;
 static {
 iHardwareService = getHardwareService();
  setFlashEnabledMethod = getSetFlashEnabledMethod(iHardwareService);
 if (iHardwareService == null) {
 Log.v(TAG, "This device does supports control of a flashlight");
  } else {
 Log.v(TAG, "This device does not support control of a flashlight");
 }
 }

  private FlashlightManager() {
  }

 private static Object getHardwareService() {
Class<?> serviceManagerClass = maybeForName("android.os.ServiceManager");
  if (serviceManagerClass == null) {
return null;
  }

 Method getServiceMethod = maybeGetMethod(serviceManagerClass, "getService",  
 String.class);
if (getServiceMethod == null) {
return null;
   }

 Object hardwareService = invoke(getServiceMethod, null, "hardware");
if (hardwareService == null) {
 return null;
}

Class<?> iHardwareServiceStubClass = maybeForName("android.os.IHardwareService$Stub");
if (iHardwareServiceStubClass == null) {
 return null;
}

 Method asInterfaceMethod = maybeGetMethod(iHardwareServiceStubClass, "asInterface",  
 IBinder.class);
 if (asInterfaceMethod == null) {
 return null;
 }

 return invoke(asInterfaceMethod, null, hardwareService);
 }

  private static Method getSetFlashEnabledMethod(Object iHardwareService) {
  if (iHardwareService == null) {
 return null;
}
  Class<?> proxyClass = iHardwareService.getClass();
 return maybeGetMethod(proxyClass, "setFlashlightEnabled", boolean.class);
 }

 private static Class<?> maybeForName(String name) {
 try {
 return Class.forName(name);
 } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
// OK
return null;
} catch (RuntimeException re) {
 Log.w(TAG, "Unexpected error while finding class " + name, re);
 return null;
 }
 }

private static Method maybeGetMethod(Class<?> clazz, String name, Class<?>...  
argClasses) {
 try {
return clazz.getMethod(name, argClasses);
} catch (NoSuchMethodException nsme) {
// OK
return null;
} catch (RuntimeException re) {
Log.w(TAG, "Unexpected error while finding method " + name, re);
 return null;
  }
  }

 private static Object invoke(Method method, Object instance, Object... args) {
  try {
 return method.invoke(instance, args);
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
 Log.w(TAG, "Unexpected error while invoking " + method, e);
return null;
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
Log.w(TAG, "Unexpected error while invoking " + method, e.getCause());
 return null;
 } catch (RuntimeException re) {
Log.w(TAG, "Unexpected error while invoking " + method, re);
 return null;
  }
 }

 static void enableFlashlight() {
 setFlashlight(true);
 }

 static void disableFlashlight() {
 setFlashlight(false);
}

 private static void setFlashlight(boolean active) {
   if (iHardwareService != null) {
  invoke(setFlashEnabledMethod, iHardwareService, active);
 }
 }

 }
```

---

```
package com.zijunlin.Zxing.Demo.camera;

 import android.content.Context;
 import android.graphics.Point;
 import android.hardware.Camera;
  import android.os.Build;
 import android.util.Log;
  import android.view.Display;
  import android.view.WindowManager;

 import java.util.regex.Pattern;

  final class CameraConfigurationManager {

  private static final String TAG = CameraConfigurationManager.class.getSimpleName();

 private static final int TEN_DESIRED_ZOOM = 27;
  private static final int DESIRED_SHARPNESS = 30;

 private static final Pattern COMMA_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(",");

 private final Context context;
 private Point screenResolution;
 private Point cameraResolution;
  private int previewFormat;
  private String previewFormatString;

  CameraConfigurationManager(Context context) {
 this.context = context;
 }

 /**
 * Reads, one time, values from the camera that are needed by the app.
 */
 void initFromCameraParameters(Camera camera) {
 Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
 previewFormat = parameters.getPreviewFormat();
  previewFormatString = parameters.get("preview-format");
 Log.d(TAG, "Default preview format: " + previewFormat + '/' + previewFormatString);
 WindowManager manager = (WindowManager)  
 context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
 Display display = manager.getDefaultDisplay();
 screenResolution = new Point(display.getWidth(), display.getHeight());
  Log.d(TAG, "Screen resolution: " + screenResolution);
  cameraResolution = getCameraResolution(parameters, screenResolution);
 Log.d(TAG, "Camera resolution: " + screenResolution);
  }

  /**
 * Sets the camera up to take preview images which are used for both preview and   
 decoding.
  * We detect the preview format here so that buildLuminanceSource() can build an   
  appropriate
 * LuminanceSource subclass. In the future we may want to force YUV420SP as it's the   
    smallest,
    * and the planar Y can be used for barcode scanning without a copy in some cases.
   */
  void setDesiredCameraParameters(Camera camera) {
  Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
  Log.d(TAG, "Setting preview size: " + cameraResolution);
  parameters.setPreviewSize(cameraResolution.x, cameraResolution.y);
  setFlash(parameters);
  setZoom(parameters);
  //setSharpness(parameters);
  camera.setParameters(parameters);
  }

 Point getCameraResolution() {
 return cameraResolution;
  } 

 Point getScreenResolution() {
 return screenResolution;
 }

 int getPreviewFormat() {
 return previewFormat;
  }

String getPreviewFormatString() {
 return previewFormatString;
  }

  private static Point getCameraResolution(Camera.Parameters parameters, Point  
  screenResolution) {

  String previewSizeValueString = parameters.get("preview-size-values");
  // saw this on Xperia
  if (previewSizeValueString == null) {
  previewSizeValueString = parameters.get("preview-size-value");
   }

     Point cameraResolution = null;

   if (previewSizeValueString != null) {
 Log.d(TAG, "preview-size-values parameter: " + previewSizeValueString);
  cameraResolution = findBestPreviewSizeValue(previewSizeValueString,  
 screenResolution);
   }

   if (cameraResolution == null) {
 // Ensure that the camera resolution is a multiple of 8, as the screen may not be.
  cameraResolution = new Point(
   (screenResolution.x >> 3) << 3,
   (screenResolution.y >> 3) << 3);
   }

   return cameraResolution;
  }

  private static Point findBestPreviewSizeValue(CharSequence previewSizeValueString,  
 Point screenResolution) {
 int bestX = 0;
 int bestY = 0;
 int diff = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
  for (String previewSize : COMMA_PATTERN.split(previewSizeValueString)) {

  previewSize = previewSize.trim();
 int dimPosition = previewSize.indexOf('x');
 if (dimPosition < 0) {
   Log.w(TAG, "Bad preview-size: " + previewSize);
   continue;
  }

  int newX;
  int newY;
  try {
    newX = Integer.parseInt(previewSize.substring(0, dimPosition));
 newY = Integer.parseInt(previewSize.substring(dimPosition + 1));
  } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
 Log.w(TAG, "Bad preview-size: " + previewSize);
 continue;
   }

   int newDiff = Math.abs(newX - screenResolution.x) + Math.abs(newY -  
  screenResolution.y);
  if (newDiff == 0) {
 bestX = newX;
bestY = newY;
break;
 } else if (newDiff < diff) {
 bestX = newX;
 bestY = newY;
diff = newDiff;
  }

 }

 if (bestX > 0 && bestY > 0) {
  return new Point(bestX, bestY);
 }
  return null;
  }

  private static int findBestMotZoomValue(CharSequence stringValues, int  
   tenDesiredZoom)  {
 int tenBestValue = 0;
 for (String stringValue : COMMA_PATTERN.split(stringValues)) {
 stringValue = stringValue.trim();
  double value;
 try {
 value = Double.parseDouble(stringValue);
 } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
 return tenDesiredZoom;
 }
  int tenValue = (int) (10.0 * value);
  if (Math.abs(tenDesiredZoom - value) < Math.abs(tenDesiredZoom - tenBestValue)) {
  tenBestValue = tenValue;
  }
  }
    return tenBestValue;
  }

  private void setFlash(Camera.Parameters parameters) {
 // FIXME: This is a hack to turn the flash off on the Samsung Galaxy.
 // And this is a hack-hack to work around a different value on the Behold II
 // Restrict Behold II check to Cupcake, per Samsung's advice
 //if (Build.MODEL.contains("Behold II") &&
  //    CameraManager.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE) {
 if (Build.MODEL.contains("Behold II") && CameraManager.SDK_INT == 3) { // 3 = Cupcake
 parameters.set("flash-value", 1);
 } else {
 parameters.set("flash-value", 2);
 }
  // This is the standard setting to turn the flash off that all devices should honor.
 parameters.set("flash-mode", "off");
  }

 private void setZoom(Camera.Parameters parameters) {

 String zoomSupportedString = parameters.get("zoom-supported");
  if (zoomSupportedString != null && !Boolean.parseBoolean(zoomSupportedString)) {
  return;
  }

  int tenDesiredZoom = TEN_DESIRED_ZOOM;

 String maxZoomString = parameters.get("max-zoom");
 if (maxZoomString != null) {
 try {
 int tenMaxZoom = (int) (10.0 * Double.parseDouble(maxZoomString));
 if (tenDesiredZoom > tenMaxZoom) {
  tenDesiredZoom = tenMaxZoom;
 }
 } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
 Log.w(TAG, "Bad max-zoom: " + maxZoomString);
 }
 }

 String takingPictureZoomMaxString = parameters.get("taking-picture-zoom-max");
  if (takingPictureZoomMaxString != null) {
 try {
 int tenMaxZoom = Integer.parseInt(takingPictureZoomMaxString);
 if (tenDesiredZoom > tenMaxZoom) {
  tenDesiredZoom = tenMaxZoom;
 }
 } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
 Log.w(TAG, "Bad taking-picture-zoom-max: " + takingPictureZoomMaxString);
  }
 }

 String motZoomValuesString = parameters.get("mot-zoom-values");
 if (motZoomValuesString != null) {
 tenDesiredZoom = findBestMotZoomValue(motZoomValuesString, tenDesiredZoom);
 }

 String motZoomStepString = parameters.get("mot-zoom-step");
 if (motZoomStepString != null) {
   try {
 double motZoomStep = Double.parseDouble(motZoomStepString.trim());
 int tenZoomStep = (int) (10.0 * motZoomStep);
 if (tenZoomStep > 1) {
  tenDesiredZoom -= tenDesiredZoom % tenZoomStep;
  }
  } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
 // continue
  }
 }

 // Set zoom. This helps encourage the user to pull back.
 // Some devices like the Behold have a zoom parameter
  if (maxZoomString != null || motZoomValuesString != null) {
   parameters.set("zoom", String.valueOf(tenDesiredZoom / 10.0));
 }
  // Most devices, like the Hero, appear to expose this zoom parameter.
 // It takes on values like "27" which appears to mean 2.7x zoom
  if (takingPictureZoomMaxString != null) {
 parameters.set("taking-picture-zoom", tenDesiredZoom);
 }
 }

 /*
  private void setSharpness(Camera.Parameters parameters) {

 int desiredSharpness = DESIRED_SHARPNESS;

 String maxSharpnessString = parameters.get("sharpness-max");
 if (maxSharpnessString != null) {
  try {
 int maxSharpness = Integer.parseInt(maxSharpnessString);
  if (desiredSharpness > maxSharpness) {
  desiredSharpness = maxSharpness;
  }
  } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
  Log.w(TAG, "Bad sharpness-max: " + maxSharpnessString);
 }
   }

 parameters.set("sharpness", desiredSharpness);
  }
 */
  }
```

---

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses- 
  permission>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: You say it's your code, but this is plainly copied from an old version of zxing.

Comment: Sean, it's clear OP is not a native speaker so you could give the benefit of the doubt wrt "my source code" (could OP have meant "the source code I am using"?)

Answer (score 0):

you can see simple flashlight operations in the example working code here:
https://bitbucket.org/hqureshi/yafa
its simple open source flashlight app for android.