# How to turn ON flashlight when device screen is off?

Tags: android, android-permissions, torch, flashlight

In my app I need to start the flashlight in an activity that is started by a BroadcastReceiver.
It works fine if the app is in foreground or background and the screen is ON but if the screen is OFF (with or without keyguard lock), the app crashes.

Analysis: 
When screen is OFF, creating the camera object still succeeds, but
Camera.startPreview() throws RuntimeException.

I can understand the motiviation to forbid camera activation when screen is off, but how can I just turn on/off the flashlight?

```
cam = Camera.open();
//...
try {
     cam.startPreview();
}catch(RuntimeException e){
    Log.w(TAG,"Failed opening camera preview. Maybe screen locked?: " + e.getMessage());
    return;
}
```

Permissions:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

I tried using the FLASHLIGHT (undocumented) permission, but it is ignored during runtime.

Tested on Android 8.1, Xiaomi Mi A1
minSdkVersion 22

Links I searched:

[flash light is not turned on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342210/flash-light-is-not-turned-on)

[flashlight not working,when device screen is off/sleep (android studio)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38541837/flashlight-not-working-when-device-screen-is-off-sleep-android-studio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the screen is off, the Activity won't actually be launched until its turned on.  That's why the camera won't turn on.  Instead, start a service to do it which can actually run immediately.

Comment: I moved the Camera.openpreview() to Service.onCreate() and now it works!
I suspect that there was a race condition between the activity starting and the camera opening. Using the service avoided that path.